# Constraint the drag/drop of RadDock

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am using `ASP.NET 3.5`.

In `Teleric, Rad Dock Control`, It has the ability to move the `Dock` towards `Left`, `Right`, `Top` and `Bottom`.

My query is, How can we restrict the user to move the `Rad Dock` out of the Visible Part towards the `Right/Bottom` Direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Research says, It is not possible as told by `Teleric` Admin
>
> ## **[here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/docking/constraint-the-move-of-raddock.aspx#tForumTop)**